# SDK for developing Android Games based on Java

Tags: java, android, sdk

Just as the title says, can you guys provide me the name of any "good" SDK for develop games in Android, but based in Java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is considered off-topic since games is a broad/opinionated topic. See: http://stackoverflow.com/tour If you did any searching you might have found this: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/37357/which-all-are-the-best-android-2d-java-based-gaming-libraries-frameworks

Answer (score 1):

have a look to [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/), it's a really interesting engine for 2d and OpenGL Android games. It works with Android Studio.

Comment: I used AndEngine a couple years ago and thought I was pretty good. However, I think the project has no life anymore. The blog and forums don't look active.

Comment: Here is a really funny game (developed recently) with andEngine: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uy.chaoscube&hl=es_419